# Flutter position Button

Tags: flutter, dart

I need a button in flutter in a specific position.
The positions should be:
Horizontal in the center and vertical on e.g. 500px.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

**1.** You can use a `Positioned` widget inside an `Stack` to wrap the button with, giving it `top` of 500, and set `alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center` for the `Stack` to center its children:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Positioned(
            top: 500,
            child: RaisedButton(
              color: Colors.yellow,
              onPressed: () {  },
              child: Text('press me'),
              )
          ),
        ]
      )
    );
  }
```

**2.** You can use `Row` with `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center` set to center its children horizontally, and a `Container` with `margin` set to 500 only for top to wrap the button with.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 500),
              child: RaisedButton(
                color: Colors.yellow,
                onPressed: () {  },
                child: Text('press me'),
              )
          )
        ]
      )
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Align` for absolute position and `Positioned` for relative position.

Here is a good [article](https://medium.com/codespace69/flutter-widget-positioning-eca4fea1528b)